# Как в админке django выводить подкатегории только для выбранной категории?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

В админке django надо при выборе категории в одном поле показывать в поле Подкатегории только относящиеся к выбранной категории подкатегории. 
Вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Попробовал применить это [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843241/django-admin-how-to-populate-select-options-depending-on-another-select), но у меня оно не работает. 
models.py:

```js
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Название', db_index=True)
    cat_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="SLUG")

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_categories():
        return Category.objects.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cat_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category', kwargs={'cat_slug': self.cat_slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        ordering = ['cat_name']


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    subcategories = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True,
                                      verbose_name='Категория')
    scat_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название')
    scat_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="SLUG")

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_subcategories():
        return SubCategory.objects.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.scat_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('subcategory', kwargs={'scat_slug': self.scat_slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'ПодКатегории'
        verbose_name = 'ПодКатегория'
        ordering = ['scat_name']


class Product(models.Model):
    # category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='produits', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, related_name='produits', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    price = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Цена")
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="Категория")
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('SubCategory', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="ПодКатегория")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, verbose_name="Название")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Текст")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/%Y/%m/%d/", verbose_name="Фото")
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Создано")
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Обновлено")
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Опубликовано")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product', kwargs={'prod_slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товары'
        ordering = ['id']
```

views.py:

```js
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
import json
from .models import *

menu = ["Главная", "Обратная связь", "Войти"]


def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    subcategories = SubCategory.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products,
               'subcategories': subcategories,
               'categories': categories,
               'menu': menu,
               'title': 'Главная страница',
               'cat_selected': 0,
               'sub_cat_selected': 0,
               }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)


def get_subcategory(request):
    scat_id = request.GET.get('id', '')
    result = list(SubCategory.objects.filter(id=int(scat_id)).values('id', 'scat_name'))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")


def pageNotFound(request, exception):
    return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Страница не найдена</h1>')
```

admin.py:

```js
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from .models import *


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'name')
    search_fields = ('name',)
    prepopulated_fields = {"cat_slug": ("name",)}


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  # поля в админке
    list_display = ('id', 'category', 'subcategory', 'title', 'time_create', 'get_html_photo', 'is_published')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'title')
    search_fields = ('title', 'content')
    list_editable = ('is_published',)
    list_filter = ('is_published', 'time_create')
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
    fields = (
        'category', 'subcategory', 'title', 'slug', 'content', 'photo', 'get_html_photo', 'price', 'is_published',
        'time_create',
        'time_update')
    readonly_fields = ('time_create', 'time_update', 'get_html_photo')
    save_on_top = True

    def get_html_photo(self, object):
        if object.photo:
            return mark_safe(f"<img src='{object.photo.url}' width=50>")

    get_html_photo.short_description = "Фото"


class SubCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'subcategories', 'scat_name')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'scat_name')
    search_fields = ('scat_name',)
    prepopulated_fields = {"scat_slug": ("scat_name",)}


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'cat_name')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'cat_name')
    search_fields = ('cat_name',)
    prepopulated_fields = {"cat_slug": ("cat_name",)}


admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(SubCategory, SubCategoryAdmin)

admin.site.site_title = 'Админка сайта'  # Название вкладки в браузере
admin.site.site_header = 'Админка'  # Заголовок в админке
```

urls.py:

```js
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

from main.views import get_subcategory
from medisearch import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    re_path(r'^getSubcategory/$', get_subcategory),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

change_form.html:

```js
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
// inspect html to check id of category select dropdown.
$(document).on("change", "select#id_category", function () {
$.getJSON("/getSubcategory/", { id: $(this).val() }, function (j) {
var options = '<option value="">---------</option>';
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
options +=
'<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + "</option>";
}
// inspect html to check id of subcategory select dropdown.
$("select#id_subcategory").html(options);
});
});
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так сделано? Или есть другие рабочие варианты решений?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой вопрос легко решается с помощью [django-smart-selects](https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)